# How to take the last line of the same Name from text file?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, gridview, text-files

i'm trying to load some data into gridview, sorry if my phrasing is bad or weird, but what i mean exactly is, lets say my text file has this data

```
Name1,123
Name1,133
Name1,143
Name2,533
Name2,233
Name2,973
Name2,313
Name3,533
Name3,233
Name3,973
Name3,213
...
```

and i only want to take the last line of Name1, Name2, Name3 and inserting to gridview

```
Name1,143
Name2,313
Name3,213
```

subsequently, i'll be trying to update the gridview cells, if further down in the text file there is the same Name again. but yeah. i'm trying to even get this part first.

so i have been trying to use foreach to try to readline and like add them all in and then removing the ones that have the same Name. but it's not removing any of it.

my codes currently is

```
public class LiveData
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public static List<LiveData> LoadDataFromFile(string path)
    {
        var data = new List<LiveData>();

        foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(path))
        {
            var dataLine = line.Split(',');

            data.Add(new LiveData
            {
                Name = dataLine[0],
                Price = Convert.ToDouble(dataLine[1])
            });
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

and

```
    private void btnLoadLDgridView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(tbTSSelectFile.Text);

        List<LiveData> list = LiveData.LoadDataFromFile(tbTSSelectFile.Text);
        List<LiveData> lst2 = LiveData.LoadDataFromFile(tbTSSelectFile.Text);

        while (file.ReadLine() != null)
        {
            string name = lst2[0].Name;
            foreach (LiveData item in list)
            {
                if (item.Name == name)
                {
                    lst2.Add(item);
                }

            }
            foreach (LiveData item in list)
            {
                if (item.Name == name)
                {
                    lst2.Remove(item);
                }
            }
        gvLiveData.DataSource = lst2;        

    }
```

i'm thinking maybe .Last can be used but i am not sure how to implement it.
the text file data is supposedly Live Stocks data, hence the need to update later on.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: You don't need to remove the value, just overwrite for each key as you iterate through each key-value pair.  The last value will be the... err, last value for each key :)

Comment: hi i realised after trying it out that this key-value pair doesnt work for me as i actually have more than just 2 values. cause i was just giving an example. is there a different way i can do this? that's not linq, cause i dont get linq..

Answer (score 0):

After you've parsed your file into the `data` variable, you could try using Linq:

```
var lastItems = data.GroupBy(d => d.Name).Select(g => g.Last());
```

This utilizes the [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534304(v=vs.100).aspx) and [Last](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb358775(v=vs.100).aspx) operators.